# If a very massive object enters in a rotating black hole retrograde orbit should it slow down the black hole's spin?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

If a very massive object is orbiting retrograde around a rotating black hole, would it slow down the black hole's spin? Of course, due to its interaction with the black hole's rotating frame, better known from the so called phenomena of frame dragging?

Comment: Since angular momentum is conserved, the answer seems self evident. Is there a deeper meaning  to your question?

Comment: @safesphere I wanted to ask in reality this... Has this frame a equivalent of mass?

Comment: Frame dragging is the effect of gravity and gravity works both ways: the Earth pulls you down with the same force as you pull the Earth up. So, as the horizon drags the object along, the object pulls the horizon back to slow down.